# How to Get Max value from columns per day from many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the case:

I am collecting data from several Sources about Companies, but let us Your customer approach

I can get several rows the same day or one row another day for the same customer. I wish to use SCD2 to keep history, but some of the Sources are not giving me data for all Fields. I could get let's say 'N/A' or NULL i
I want to do this

a) if the two or more rows are identical except date, should result in one row With oldest date
b) if one or more Fields are changed, create a New scd2 row With changed date as startdate. 
c) if one or several fields in the New row in b) has changed from a legal value to 'N/A', it should have the latest legal value (from the previous row) for those Fields

I am using sql server and t-sql

I hope i explained me clear enough :-)

Thanks again

EDIT (from comments):

```
CustomerHistoryId   |CustomerNum    |CustomerName   |Planet |ChangeDate --------------------------------------------------------------------------------‌​----------------- 
1   |101    |Anakin Skywalker   |Tatooine   |14.03.2015 15:41
2   |102    |Yoda   |Coruscant  |14.03.2015 15:41
3   |103    |Obi-Wan Kenobi |Coruscant  |24.03.2015 15:41
4   |102    |Yoda |Coruscant    |29.03.2015 15:41
5   |102    |Yoda   |NULL   |03.04.2015 15:41
6   |102    |Yoda   |NULL   |04.04.2015 
7   |103    |Obi-Wan Kenobi |Degobah    |08.04.2015 15:41
8   |102    |Master Yoda    |Tatooine   |09.04.2015 15:41
9   |102    |NULL   |Tatooine   |10.04.2015 15:41
10  |102    |Master Yoda    |Tatooine   |11.04.2015 15:41
```

Final result:

```
CustomerHistoryId   |CustomerNum    |CustomerName   |Planet |ChangeDate
1   |101    |Anakin Skywalker   |Tatooine   |14.03.2015 15:41
2   |102    |Yoda   |Coruscant  |14.03.2015 15:41
3   |103    |Obi-Wan Kenobi |Coruscant  |24.03.2015 15:41
7   |103    |Obi-Wan Kenobi |Degobah    |08.04.2015 15:41
8   |102 |Master Yoda   |Tatooine   |09.04.2015 15:41
```

Comment: You are not being clear enough.  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Comment: Sorry. I have some data that would explain

Comment: My case is variant of datawarehouse Dimension slowly change Dimension type 2. Identical rows up to a change must be considered as one row, the first row. A change in some of the Fields in a New row must be included in the data set but if the Fields includes a null value, it must be replaced by previous value of previous row

Comment: CustomerHistoryId |CustomerNum |CustomerName  |Planet  |ChangeDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |101  |Anakin Skywalker |Tatooine |14.03.2015 15:41
2   |102  |Yoda   |Coruscant |14.03.2015 15:41
3   |103  |Obi-Wan Kenobi  |Coruscant |24.03.2015 15:41
4   |102  |Yoda   |Coruscant |29.03.2015 15:41
5   |102  |Yoda   |NULL  |03.04.2015 15:41
6   |102  |Yoda   |NULL  |04.04.2015 15:41
to be followed

Comment: 7   |103  |Obi-Wan Kenobi  |Degobah |08.04.2015 15:41
8   |102  |Master Yoda  |Tatooine |09.04.2015 15:41
9   |102  |NULL   |Tatooine |10.04.2015 15:41
10   |102  |Master Yoda  |Tatooine |11.04.2015 15:41

Comment: Final result:         CustomerHistoryId |CustomerNum |CustomerName  |Planet  |ChangeDate
1   |101  |Anakin Skywalker |Tatooine |14.03.2015 15:41
2   |102  |Yoda   |Coruscant |14.03.2015 15:41
3   |103  |Obi-Wan Kenobi  |Coruscant |24.03.2015 15:41
7   |103  |Obi-Wan Kenobi  |Degobah |08.04.2015 15:41
8   |102  |Master Yoda  |Tatooine |09.04.2015 15:41

Comment: You can delete your comments.  In the future, such information goes in the question, not the comments.

Comment: This is trickier than you realize, especially since you need to do it on multiple columns. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you want to ignore rows with `NULL` values and then ignore duplicates, ignoring dates.  Assuming that the ids and dates are assigned in the same order, you can do this with aggregation:

```
select min(CustomerHistoryId) as CustomerHistoryId,
       CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, min(ChangeDate) as ChangeDate
from t
where CustomerName is not null and Planet is not null
group by CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet;
```

Comment: Thx for the fast respond. I will try this :-)

Comment: Hello again. Your answer is correct in many way but if for instance CustomerName is NULL it must correct the value to the last legal value. I will create a New example

Comment: CustomerHistoryId CustomerNum CustomerName Planet ChangeDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |101 |Anakin Skywalker |Tatooine |2015-03-16 22:18:34.713
2 |102 |Yoda   |Coruscant |2015-03-16 00:42:34.717
3 |103 |Obi-Wan Kenobi  |Coruscant |2015-03-26 22:18:34.713
4 |102 |Yoda   |Coruscant |2015-03-16 03:06:34.713
5 |102 |Yoda   |Empty  |2015-03-16 05:30:34.717
6 |102 |Yoda   |Basic  |2015-03-16 07:54:34.713
7 |103 |Obi-Wan Kenobi  |Degobah |2015-04-10 22:18:34.713

Comment: I am sorry about the format here. This text Box has too few characters

Comment: CustomerHistoryId CustomerNum CustomerName Planet ChangeDate

1|101|Anakin Skywalker|Tatooine|2015-03-16 22:18:34.713
2|102|Yoda|Coruscant|2015-03-16 00:42:34.717
3|103|Obi-Wan Kenobi|Coruscant|2015-03-26 22:18:34.713
4|102|Yoda|Coruscant|2015-03-16 03:06:34.713
5|102|Yoda|NULL|2015-03-16 05:30:34.717
6|102|Yoda|Basic|2015-03-16 07:54:34.713
7|103|Obi-Wan Kenobi|Degobah|2015-04-10 22:18:34.713
8|102|Master Yoda|Tatooine|2015-04-11 00:42:34.717
9|102|NULL|Tatooine|2015-04-11 03:06:34.713
10|102|NULL|Tatooine2|2015-04-11 07:54:34.713
11|102|Master Yoda|Degobah2|2015-04-13 22:18:34.713

Comment: Should result in this:CustomerHistoryId|CustomerNum|CustomerName|Planet|ChangeDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1|101|Anakin Skywalker|Tatooine |2015-03-16 22:18:34.713
2|102|Yoda|Coruscant|2015-03-16 00:42:34.717
3|103|Obi-Wan Kenobi|Coruscant|2015-03-26 22:18:34.713
6|102|Yoda|Basic|2015-03-16 07:54:34.713
7|103|Obi-Wan Kenobi|Degobah|2015-04-10 22:18:34.713
8|102|Master Yoda|Tatooine|2015-04-11 00:42:34.717
10|102|Master Yoda|Tatooine2|2015-04-11 07:54:34.713
11|102|Master Yoda|Degobah2|2015-04-13 22:18:34.713

Comment: do NOT include new data/results into comments... UPDATE your question instead please (try a copy/paste of those comments all line breaks are lost)

Answer (score 0):

```
| customerhistoryid | customernum |     customername |    planet |              changedate |
|-------------------|-------------|------------------|-----------|-------------------------|
|                 1 |         101 | Anakin Skywalker |  Tatooine | March, 16 2015 22:18:34 |
|                 2 |         102 |             Yoda | Coruscant | March, 16 2015 00:42:34 |
|                 3 |         103 |   Obi-Wan Kenobi | Coruscant | March, 26 2015 22:18:34 |
|                 4 |         102 |             Yoda | Coruscant | March, 16 2015 03:06:34 |
|                 5 |         102 |             Yoda |    (null) | March, 16 2015 05:30:34 |
|                 6 |         102 |             Yoda |     Basic | March, 16 2015 07:54:34 |
|                 7 |         103 |   Obi-Wan Kenobi |   Degobah | April, 10 2015 22:18:34 |
|                 8 |         102 |      Master Yoda |  Tatooine | April, 11 2015 00:42:34 |
|                 9 |         102 |           (null) |  Tatooine | April, 11 2015 03:06:34 |
|                10 |         102 |           (null) | Tatooine2 | April, 11 2015 07:54:34 |
|                11 |         102 |      Master Yoda |  Degobah2 | April, 13 2015 22:18:34 |
```

The data isn't "clean", for example you have "Yoda" and "Master Yoda" both with the same `customernum` value. So really there should be a separate table, unique rows per `customernum` containing the correct name. However this does not exist.

So here is AN approach (there are many more possibilities)

```
select
   MIN(CustomerHistoryId), CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, MIN(ChangeDate)
from (
      select
        t.CustomerHistoryId
      , t.CustomerNum
      , COALESCE(t.CustomerName,
                   ( select top (1)
                        t2.CustomerName
                     from t t2
                     where t.CustomerName IS NULL 
                     and t2.CustomerName IS NOT NULL 
                     and t2.CustomerNum = t.CustomerNum
                     and t2.ChangeDate < t.ChangeDate
                     order by t2.ChangeDate DESC
                    )
                 ) AS CustomerName
      , COALESCE(t.Planet,
                   ( select top (1)
                        t2.Planet
                     from t t2
                     where t.Planet IS NULL 
                     and t2.Planet IS NOT NULL 
                     and t2.ChangeDate < t.ChangeDate
                     order by t2.ChangeDate DESC
                    )
                 ) AS Planet
      , t.ChangeDate
      from t
   ) dt
group by
   CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet
order by
   CustomerNum, MIN(CustomerHistoryId)
;
```

This is a reasonably generic approach but you could use `OUTER APPLY` instead of the correlated subqueries.

From that query I got this result:

```
| min | customernum |     customername |    planet |                     min |
|-----|-------------|------------------|-----------|-------------------------|
|   1 |         101 | Anakin Skywalker |  Tatooine | March, 16 2015 22:18:34 |
|   2 |         102 |             Yoda | Coruscant | March, 16 2015 00:42:34 |
|   6 |         102 |             Yoda |     Basic | March, 16 2015 07:54:34 |
|   8 |         102 |      Master Yoda |  Tatooine | April, 11 2015 00:42:34 |
|  10 |         102 |      Master Yoda | Tatooine2 | April, 11 2015 07:54:34 |
|  11 |         102 |      Master Yoda |  Degobah2 | April, 13 2015 22:18:34 |
|   3 |         103 |   Obi-Wan Kenobi | Coruscant | March, 26 2015 22:18:34 |
|   7 |         103 |   Obi-Wan Kenobi |   Degobah | April, 10 2015 22:18:34 |
```

I used [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/da035/1) (in Postgres as MSSQL wasn't working at the time)